# Check if last Child in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to know while retrieving the data from Firebase if this is the last child or not ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) Please look at [ask]. This site isn't a code generator.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#getParent()):

> public DatabaseReference getParent()
> A DatabaseReference to the parent location, or null if this instance references the root location
>
> public DatabaseReference getRoot()
> A reference to the root location of this Firebase Database

So you can use getRoot() on your DatabaseReference object to always go to the root, or getParent() until you get null.

You should be structuring your data in a flattened structure so that you are not confused about where the data ends ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)):

> Avoid nesting data
>
> Because the Firebase Realtime Database allows nesting data up to 32 levels deep, you might be tempted to think that this should be the default structure. However, when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep your data structure as flat as possible.